# Uninstall the Add-on setup before uninstall the main setup using Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

My requirement is below; I have read the Add-on Product Id from registry and uninstall the setup using that product ID before uninstall the Main setup.
I have used the below code

```
[code]
const
  RegProductLocation = 'SOFTWARE\My Company\My Product\Sample\ {#Version}';
var SamplesProductId : string;
function GetSamplesID(): Boolean;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RegProductLocation, 'ProductID', SamplesProductId) then
begin
    Result:= true;
end else begin
Result:= false;   
  end;end;

[UninstallRun] 
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: " /x ""{SamplesProductId}"" /qn"; Check:GetSamplesID();  Flags: runhidden;
```

It is not compiled by Inno setup and shows error. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It would probably help for someone to answer if (1) you'd format your code properly, (2) tell the error you're getting, (3) tell which line the compiler shows the error, (4) tell how 'Version', 'SamplesProductId' etc are defined.. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a function and a `{code:...}` constant to access data from `[Code]`

Something like this (untested air code):

```
[UninstallRun] 
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: "/x ""{code:GetSamplesID}"" /qn"; Check:CheckHasSamplesID(); Flags: runhidden; 

[code]
const
  RegProductLocation = 'SOFTWARE\My Company\My Product\Sample\{#Version}';
var
  SamplesProductId : string;

function CheckHasSamplesID(): Boolean;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RegProductLocation, 'ProductID', SamplesProductId) then begin
    Result:= true;
  end else begin
    Result:= false;   
  end;
end;

function GetSamplesID(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result:= SamplesProductId;
end;
```

Note there was an extrenuous space in your `RegProductLocation` constant.

Comment: Hi Deanna, Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt; I have tried with product ID hardcode in Script is working, But read from registry no luck. I am installing the Main setup first then install the Add-on setup. The Add-on setup only writes the product ID in registry. So when the main setup install there is no product Id in registry. Is Inno setup read the product Id while uninstalling? Since the product Id won’t available in registry while main setup install.